# caret: Attempt to Predict but prediction row differs

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I've created and tuned multiple models, but I run into issues when I try to predict them. I first run my code as followed to tune an LDA model.

```
library(MASS)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
data(survey)
data<-survey

#create training and test set
split <- createDataPartition(data$W.Hnd, p=.8)[[1]]
train<-data[split,]
test<-data[-split,]


#creating training parameters
control <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                        number = 10, 
                        p =.8, 
                        savePredictions = TRUE, 
                        classProbs = TRUE, 
                        summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

#fitting and tuning model
lda_tune <- train(W.Hnd ~ . , 
            data=train, 
            method = "glm" ,
            metric = "ROC",
            trControl = control)
```

However when I run 
`results <- predict(rf_tune, newdata=test)`,

the output is only 32 rows, when the test set has 46 rows. This is problematic as I create a `data.frame` of the test results with the predicted values from multiple models to analyze using a confusion matrix. For instance, when I run this

```
results<-data.frame(obs = test$W.Hnd, lda = predict(lda_tune, newdata = test))
```

I get the error `Error in`$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "rf_results", value = c(2L, 2L, 2L,  : 
  replacement has 32 rows, data has 46`

Can someone explain to me why caret is returning 32 predicted values when there are clearly 46 values to predict or when I explicitly call the model to predict the values in the test set?

Comment: Do you mean `results <- predict(lda_tune, newdata=test)`?

Comment: I think your problem is that `test` contains missing values.  `nrow(test[complete.cases(test), ])` gives me `34`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your code resulted in errors on my side. The twoClasSummary returns an error. But ignoring that, you are first talking about lda_tune and later about rf_tune.

Accounting for these issues, the problem lies with missing values in your test set. If you check `nrow(test[complete.cases(test), ])` you will see that it returns 33 cases. Which is exactly what the predict returns.

I added the code below for refence. Including rf_tune and lda_tune + their results.

```
library(MASS)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
data(survey)
data<-survey

#create training and test set
split <- createDataPartition(data$W.Hnd, p=.8)[[1]]
train<-data[split,]
test<-data[-split,]


#creating training parameters
control <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                        number = 10, 
                        p =.8, 
                        savePredictions = TRUE, 
                        classProbs = TRUE)

#fitting and tuning model
lda_tune <- train(W.Hnd ~ . , 
                  data=train, 
                  method = "glm" ,
                  metric = "ROC",
                  trControl = control)

rf_tune <- train(W.Hnd ~ . , 
                  data=train, 
                  method = "rf" ,
                  metric = "ROC",
                  trControl = control)

lda_results <- data.frame(obs = test$W.Hnd[complete.cases(test)], lda = predict(lda_tune, newdata = test))
rf_results <- data.frame(obs = test$W.Hnd[complete.cases(test)], lda = predict(rf_tune, newdata = test))
```

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks!